What's the intuition for the extended accounting equation?
I'm a beginner to accounting, trying to get the hang of the basic concepts. I first posted this on the economics stack, where it was closed as off-topic. I suspect the same would happen on the money stack.

The wikipedia article on debits and credits contains the extended accounting equation,
$$\text{Assets}+\text{Expenses}=\text{Equity}+\text{Liabilities}+\text{Income}.\tag{1.1}$$
I rewrite this as
\begin{align}
\text{Equity}
& = (\text{Assets}-\text{Liabilities})-(\text{Income}-\text{Expenses}) \tag{1.2} \\
& = \text{Net assets}-\text{Net income} \tag{1.3}
\end{align}
but I find it non-intuitive that equity should result from subtracting net income from net assets.
On the other hand, the wikipedia article on equity say,

Equity is measured for accounting purposes by subtracting liabilities from the value of the assets owned.

I can see how this makes sense. But then wouldn't it make sense for this to be extended to
\begin{align}
\text{Equity}
& = (\text{Assets}+\text{Income})-(\text{Liabilities}+\text{Expenses}) \tag{2.1} \\
& = (\text{Assets}-\text{Liabilities})+(\text{Income}-\text{Expenses}) \tag{2.2} \\
& = \text{Net assets}+\text{Net income} \tag{2.3}
\end{align}
where the sign on $\text{Net income}$ has changed relative to $(1.3)$?
$(2.3)$ makes more sense to me than $(1.3)$, but I guess $(2.3$) is incorrect.
Can anyone clarify?

I find a lot of things in accounting to be non-intuitive. The equations can only be explained in terms of how amounts are added to the various accounts. In an example later on the same Wikipedia page, they take delivery of a $$500$ computer but haven't paid for it yet. Therefore "Equipment (Asset)" has a debit of $500$ and "Payable ABC Computers (Liability)" has a credit of $500$. Maybe when you understand that, the rest of the equations will make more sense.

@DavidK My current conceptualisation of the credit/debit terminology is that any asset (even if not even fictitiously human) owes a debt of value to the business, so that increasing the asset account of the business is increasing the debt owed to the business, hence debit increases assets. I've yet to come up with a conceptualisation that makes sense of $\text{Equity}=\text{Assets}-\text{Income}$, and I'm hoping accounting terminology is not effectively random.

Have you read at all their sentences "Here Income and Expenses are regarded as temporary or nominal accounts which pertain only to the current accounting period whereas Asset, Liability, and Equity accounts are permanent or real accounts pertaining to the lifetime of the business. The temporary accounts are closed to the Equity account at the end of the accounting period to record profit/loss for the period." ? To me this means in short that Net Income is effectively part of Equity and will be properly so at the end of the current accounting period. No puzzle whatsoever.

Thanks for this, @KurtG. I'm thinking about it and trying to reconcile it with the equations, but am currently a bit side-tracked.

The Wiki article define "Equity" as "Assets $-$ Liabilities" (general accounting equation) and define "Equity/Capital" via the extended accounting equation. The two equities are not one and the same thing, then I'd agree that using the same symbol "E" in the two equations is misleading. Call, rather, "E/C" the one in the extended equation; then:
$$E=E/C+(Income-Expenses)$$
I think that @KurtG.'s comment to the OP explains how to interpret this: think of "E/C" as the equity at the end of the previous period, and "E" as the one at the end of the current period. As they are defined in accounting terms, $Income - Expenses$ is just the quantification ("with explanations": accounts) of $\Delta Assets - \Delta Liabilities$ (namely of $\Delta Equity$) occurred in the period "just over". As it is usually said, the net income of this period is "carried over to the new period" (just google translating from my native language...), i.e. consolidated in the equity account.

Net Assets is money out and Net Income is money in, so that the first reads as a Debit column, and the second as a Credit column, so the signs of net assets and net income are different.
If you write

Equity + Net Income = Net Assets

then the credits are on the left and the debits are on the right, as usual.
